# Why can't I call a Kivy.core.image function?

Tags: python, image, kivy

I did a program using python and pyGTK. Now, I'm translating it to Kivy, for use it with a tablet (Android).  One archive.py is a custom widget with graphic information about a person (an image of her/his, a frame with color if him/his is selected, a little candle if is your birthday,..)

The question is, to make the custom widget I need to know the image size, but when I write:

```
wi = self._imagen.width()
```

I have this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Before, in code, I check self._imagen is an [kivy.core.image.Image](http://kivy.org/docs/_modules/kivy/core/image.html) object, that has a width function:

```
if self._imagen != None:
    print self._imagen          #terminal print <kivy.core.image.Image object at 0xb2f2db9c>
    wi = self._imagen.width()    #ERROR
    hi = self._imagen.height()
```

I search for any instruction in my code like: self._imagen = 1 (or other int number) (there is not).

I don't know why. Thanks and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `wi = self._imagen.width` using `wi = self._imagen.width()` is trying to call  the int object as a method, that is why you are getting the error.

```
In [1]: width = 3

In [2]: print width
3

In [3]: print width()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-33019bd92b32> in <module>()
----> 1 print width()

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```